# Color transitions animation in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to animate between colors using jQuery, i.e. to fade out one color and fade in another.

I know this can be done with CSS3 keyframes, but that doesn't work in Internet Explorer as mentioned by w3schools. I want a standard method that can work in all browsers.

On search in stackoverflow, it mentioned that a jQuery color plugin is required. Does anyone know about any simpler method for doing it?

Answer (score 10):

You can try this: [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nJKbE/)

**CSS**

```
#content {
    width: 100%; 
    background: #eff6f4;
    transition: background 4s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background 4s linear;
    -moz-transition: background 4s linear;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#content').css('background', '#C89CBD');
```

This will change the background color in 4 seconds.

**Update**

If you need IE, then you can have something like this:

```
$('#content').fadeOut(500, function(){
    $(this).css('background', bg).fadeIn(2000);
});
```

It won't be that good, but works. [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nJKbE/1/)

Comment: from the original question: "but that doesn't work in Internet Explorer"

Comment: It works ,thank you!I've done random color with transition and css() in jquery

Answer (score 1):

The [color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/) is as simple as it gets, I'm not sure what you imagine could be simpler.  All you need to do is include another script:

```
<script src="jquery.color.min.js"></script>
```

then animate the color:

```
  $(foo).animate({
      backgroundColor: "#00FF00"
  }, 1000 );
```